# Linux distro for mobile screen remote access?

Tags: distribution-choice, mobile, remote-management, touch-screen

Are there any distros that have a UI made for mobile phones? I want to setup a server that can be accessed remotely with a phone.

Comment: Not specifically a UI for phones, but if you "just" want to control your server you can use [xvnc for android](https://www.realvnc.com/products/android/) or TeamViewer which has a mobile app for iOS and android (you need a commercial license, but it is easier to set up than VNC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kali Linux NetHunter is probably the closest thing you are going to find.

[image: Kali Linux NetHunter for Nexus]

https://www.kali.org/kali-linux-nethunter/